# How can i Compare two Arrays, which don't have Same lenght in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

i have two Arrays Array1 and Array2 and i want to compare them like that they follow below three rules

**Fisrt Thing:**

```
Array1=[en,fr,eg];
Array2=[{lang:en},{lang:eg}]
```

After comparison Result will be

```
Result=[{lang:en},{lang:fr,Maybe:i_can_add_other_Attribute},{lang:eg}]
```

**Second Thing**

and if `Array1=[en,fr,eg]` and `Array2=[{lang:en},{lang:fr}]` then result should be `Result[{lang:en},{lang:fr}]`

**Third Thing**

And Array2 should be arrange as sequence of Array1 here is example

```
Array1=[en,fr,eg]
Array2=[{lang:fr},{lang:en},{lang:eg}]
```

Then it Result should become

```
 Result=[{lang:en},{lang:fr},{lang:eg}]
```

Comment: Where does `somevalue` come from?

Comment: @CertainPerformance it will be any Object that i can push

Comment: So, just overwrite `Array1 = Array2`? (possibly with a copy)

Comment: the arrays have a specific order?

Comment: Yeah Array1 have specific order mean it will same but Array2 will change time by time and compare

Comment: You're not actually doing any comparison, the result is being determined entirely by the contents of `Array1`.

Comment: Is it possible to have, say `{lang:ja}` in `Array2`? What happens in that case? And you seem to be doing a merge, rather than compare.

Comment: @KenY-N no that value cant be come there ...Array2[x].lang will only contain the value that will already available in Array1

Comment: Is the algorithm like: For each element in `Array1`: if element also in `Array2` then move from `Array2` to `Result`, else if `Array2` is empty then exit loop, else add `{lang: element, Maybe:i_can_add_other_Attribute}` to `Result`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't really care what was originally in `Array2`, only what was in `Array`. You just want to create a new array of objects directly from the values in `Array1`, which you can easily do with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const Array1 = [ 'en', 'fr', 'eg' ];
let Array2 = [ {lang:'eg'}, {lang:'fr'}, 'mashed potatoes' ];

Array2 = Array1.map( lang => ({ lang }) );

console.log( Array2 );
```

Comment: I think he wants that values that found in array2 only will preserve too...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use values from Array2 when possible you could do something like this:

```js
const Array1 = [ 'en', 'fr', 'eg' ];
const Array2 = [ { lang: 'en' }, { lang: 'eg' } ];

const combined = Array1.map(key =>
  Array2.find(obj => obj.lang === key) || { lang: key }
);
```

Comment: I think he wants that values that found in array2 only will preserve too...

Comment: @Michael If I understand you correctly then this should do that, it'll only add a new object if one isn't found in the second array. Essentially prioritizing Array2 as the "source of truth".

Comment: Yes, I think this might be what the OP wants. Although it is still quite unclear.

Comment: It also preserves the order of the first array, just saw that note from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have an array with all available langs and array of objects that have more properties about each lang, if I'm correct I recommend you to save the second array as an object to prevent scan array each time and better representing of the data:

```
let langWithProps = {
  en: {},
  fr: {}
  ...
}
```

and then you can do:

```js
let langWithProps = {
  en: {},
  fr: {}
}

const langs = [ 'en', 'fr', 'eg' ];

langs.forEach(function(value) {
    if (!langWithProps[value]) {
        langWithProps[value] = {Maybe: "you_can_add_other_Attribute"};
    }
});

console.log(langWithProps);
```